# How to display loader before video plays?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-videoview

I am using video player and want to display loader before it starts. Following is my snippet code for that. Can any one help me solve this ?

```
            showpDialog();
             String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
            String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(vid_path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
            System.out.println(urlEncoded);
            final VideoView videoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv);
            videoView.setVideoPath(rlEncoded);
            MediaController mediaController = new
            MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);    
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
          Log.i("", "Duration = " +videoView.getDuration());
        }
    });

 hidepDialog();
 videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, in `onCreate()`, before calling `runOnUiThread`, start the `dialog`

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

set a `OnPreparedListener()` that will dismiss the `dialog` when the video is ready to play

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you it is working for me.

Comment: @Nilima you are welcome..